# I want to have a dialog as a separate component in React-MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I'm using React and MUI (v5)

I want to show a dialog in my component but I want this dialog as a separate component, like:

```
function MyComponent() {

    const [ openDialog, setOpenDialog ] = useState(false);

    const handleOpenDialog = () => {
        setOpenDialog(true);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Button variant="contained" size="medium" onClick={handleOpenDialog}>
                Open Dialog
            </Button>

            <CreateCategory openDialog={openDialog} />

            <Box>
              ...
            </Box>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

and the dialog would be like:

```
export default function CreateCategory(props) {
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(props.openDialog);
  const [newCategoryName, setNewCategoryName] = useState("");

  const handleDialogClose = () => {
    setOpenDialog(false);
  };

  const handleAddCategory = (categoryName) => {
   ...
  };

  const handleCategoryNameChange = (e) => {
    setNewCategoryName(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        maxWidth={"sm"}
        open={openDialog}
        onClose={handleDialogClose}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Create Video Category</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <TextField
            ...
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button ...>
            Add Category
          </Button>
          <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleDialogClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

But it is not working, I want to reuse the dialog in another component

I have it in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-merkle-ivquu?file=/src/App.js

Rafael

Comment: *But it is not working* - this should never be included in a question without an explanation of what that actually means. Is it breaking? Is it giving unexpected results? What is happening vs what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying props into state for no reason is an anti-pattern, and it's causing your issue.

You have **two** states called `openDialog` (one in the parent and one in the child), and are expecting them to operate as if they're the same.

To correct this, use `props.openDialog` directly in your component, and pass down the setter function as a prop as well. Then remove the local state version since it won't be used anymore.

```
// Pass the setter as well
<CreateCategory openDialog={openDialog} setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog} />
```

```
const handleDialogClose = () => {
  props.setOpenDialog(false); // Use the prop.
};
```

```
<Dialog
  fullWidth
  maxWidth={"sm"}
  open={props.openDialog} // Use value directly here
  onClose={handleDialogClose}
>
```

In case this is also a source of confusion in the following snippet (which you should remove anyway):

```
const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(props.openDialog);
```

`props.openDialog` is only used **once** on the first render to initialize the state. Anytime in the future that the prop changes, the state *will not* change to match it. It is an *initial* value.

Comment: Thank you Brian

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot in understanding how to separate a Dialog component into a separate file